# In Neo4j how to group by one return key, instead of all non aggregate keys in return?

Tags: group-by, neo4j, cypher

[Neo4j documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/aggregating/) mentions that:

> 4.3. Aggregating functions To calculate aggregated data, Cypher offers aggregation, analogous to SQL’s GROUP BY.
>
> Aggregating functions take a set of values and calculate an aggregated
> value over them. Examples are avg() that calculates the average of
> multiple numeric values, or min() that finds the smallest numeric or
> string value in a set of values. When we say below that an aggregating
> function operates on a set of values, we mean these to be the result
> of the application of the inner expression (such as n.age) to all the
> records within the same aggregation group.
>
> Aggregation can be computed over all the matching subgraphs, or it can
> be further divided by introducing grouping keys. These are
> non-aggregate expressions, that are used to group the values going
> into the aggregate functions.
>
> Assume we have the following return statement:
>
> RETURN n, count(*)
>
> **We have two return expressions: n, and count(*). The first, n, is not an aggregate function, and so it will be the grouping key. The
> latter, count(*) is an aggregate expression. The matching subgraphs
> will be divided into different buckets, depending on the grouping
> key.** The aggregate function will then be run on these buckets,
> calculating an aggregate value per bucket.

I cannot figure out how to:

```
RETURN n, m COLLECT(n);
```

for example, and only use `n` as the grouping key, not both `n` and `m`.

Comment: Are you trying to count something or are you trying to collect something? And what exactly is that something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in Cypher as it does implicit group by as you have learned from the documentation. It is quite similar to SQL, except there you have to explicitly add the `GROUP BY` clause.

What you can do is use [subqueries](https://neo4j.com/developer/cypher/subqueries/), or split the query into two parts, where you first aggregate the data and then iterate over each node again in the second part.